# Waiting for threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi

I'm using CreateThread() for my 4 threads.
I would like to run all my threads simultaneously, but wait for all 4 to finish before continuing with the main thread.
I used an int and increased it at the start of the thread, then decreased it at the end, then in my main thread I used a while loop to hold while the number is over a certain value... however this didn't seem to work correctly.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mechanism of [signaled states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069) and the [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to wait for the events or threads themselves (pointed to by their handles) to reach a signalled state.

By simply sharing a single variable among those threads you're probably running into synchronization problems, especially when they are spread among your CPU's cores.

If you want to modify a shared value atomically without using synchronization mechanisms, use the "Interlocked*" functions like [InterlockedIncrement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), although that doesn't completely guarantee that there will be no problems. Don't use that method as a synchronization mechanism anyway.

Comment: You don't need events, Threads are waitable objects in Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that and modified the answer accordingly. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `bWaitAll` flag set, on all of your thread handles. The function will return once all threads exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your main thread waits until all the child threads complete their job then 
You can use:

<strike>**[pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html)**</strike>

Edit:

Ah it is windows platform(I failed to notice that before), So you need to use,

**[WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

What you will likely want to do is create the four threads and then call `WaitForSingleObject` on the four handles returned, in order.  Just make sure the four threads exit with a call to `ExitThread`.

EDIT:

Or, as pointed out in Hasturkun's answer, use `WaitForMultipleObjects`... that would be smart. :-)